# Customize zsh prompt

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

How can I remove the `[` that is placed before my commands after they are entered (e.g. the top two lines in the picture). Looking for something to put in my `.zshrc` file.

[image]

Comment: Those are [marks](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/use-marks-and-bookmarks-trml135fbc26/2.10/mac/10.15.7) added by Terminal, not anything to do with `zsh` or any particular shell.

Comment: They are displayed *by* the prompt, but are not *part of* the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

As per `chepner`, they are part of the terminal not zsh.

The way to remove them is:

*Choose Edit > Marks > Automatically Mark Prompt Lines. The tick lets you know whether the option is enabled.*